# How to create nested lists with draggable items in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, nested, draggable, vuejs3

I'm looking for a way to create nested lists with draggable elements in VueJs3 & Ionic

This is the result I'd like to have: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/treeview/drag-and-drop/

Moreover, I'd like each item of the list to be part of "ion-sliding" tag for them to have some options when they're sliding like this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/item/ItemSliding/

I tried to use "ion-reorder-group" but it doesn't allow me to create nested lists like I would like to. I also tried a bunch of librairies but I'm not able to make any of them work with my Ionic-Vue3 project.

I'm stuck on this issue and I would be very glad to have any recommendations or help !

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the question, I'm posting the solution I used in case it could be useful for someone.

I used this library: https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next that supports Vuejs 3.0

There's a very useful link to look at live demos and each of them has the code attached to it available. I combined some of them and added my "ion-sliding" tags to obtain the result expected.

It works perfectly !

Comment: Have you used it on an iOS device? I'm testing Vue.draggable (SortableJS) on an Ionic Vue 6 project as well and am having issues when running on iOS. The dragged item's position is wrong if the page has been scrolled, and dragging an item to the top or bottom edge of the viewport fails to scroll the page.

Comment: I had developed this project for Android devices. However I've extended it to a PWA to make it available also on IOS, so via a navigator it worked well on IOS too.